# Add Key To Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm looking to append keys to the array which I have created, so I have an array of numbers:

```
var Array1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
```

I want to convert the array so it looks like this:

```
Array1 = [{ x: 1 }, { x: 2 }, { x: 3 }, { x: 4 }, { x: 5 }];
```

How do I append to each value in the array like so?

https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-data-binding-in-d3-js/ - Within this article, we can see they have an array called 'Data' - An array of objects. Now I have a simple array full of numbers and I need it to be converted as described above

Comment: Your expected output is not a valid JavaScript array.

Comment: You probably want an `object` with key:value pairs

Comment: I don't mind if my expected output is even a JavaScript Object if that helps?

Comment: Is that possible? To convert an array to an object?

Comment: You want an array of objects with the property x.

Comment: How would you look up the values again? If all the elements have the same key, well, it's not possible, the point of a key is that it points to a single value.

Comment: Not really Anthony, I'm using this for D3 and how about you read this article https://www.sitepoint.com/a-beginners-guide-to-data-binding-in-d3-js/. Look at the arrays they have and you can see that each object has a key of X and Y.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) together with [short hand properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer) for a new object for each element of the array.

```js
var array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
    objects = array.map(x => ({ x }));
    
console.log(objects);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Really?!?! Pascal gave the same answer 2mins earlier, and this is still unanswerable!

Answer (score 0):

```
Array1 = Array1.map(entry => ({x: entry}));
```

Comment: See comments on question. Array of objects is fine for him so why the downvote?

Comment: He wants an object. And not an aray of objects. (I dont know what that means, thats why i voted to close)

Comment: He obviously wants an Array (that's why he noted it like this: `Array1 = [x:1,x:2,x:3,x:4,x:5];`. I'm pretty sure he wants to access the values like this: `Array1[0].x` but didn't get the notation right, which would be `Array1 = [{x: 1}, {x: 2}, {x: 3}, {x: 4}, {x: 5}];`